# Strange behavior of UITableView cells

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, behavior

I've created a UITableView containing cells (dynamic) with 2 labels and 1 UIStepper. One of these labels get synced with the value the UIStepper. So far, so good.

This is what my code looks like, when the value of a UIStepper changes:

```
- (IBAction)stepper:(id)sender {
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[[sender superview] superview];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    int row = indexPath.row;
    // I just determined in which row the user tapped the UIStepper.

    UIStepper *stepper = (UIStepper *)[cell viewWithTag:300];
    UILabel *menge = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    int anzahl = stepper.value;
    menge.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",anzahl];
    // and the label just got synced with the UIStepper value

    [_mengen insertObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",anzahl] atIndex:row];
    // and the value got saved for further calculations
}
```

The mutable array *mengen* looks like this, after pressing the **+** of the UIStepper in the first row:

```
(
    1,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0
)
```

Exactly that, I've expected!

**BUT** not only the label *menge* in the first row was set to 1, also the label in the eighth row did. If I press the **+** in the second row, the labels in the second and in the ninth row  change, and so on.

Why is this happening?

Update: cellForRowAtIndexPath method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    UILabel *artikel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:200];
    cell.selected = NO;
    [artikel setText:[_artikel objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];
    return cell;

}
```

Comment: Most probably you don't use the dequeuing feature of the table view properly. Show us your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Comment: just added the method...

Comment: I believe you are missing the `if (cell == nil) { cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] init] autorelease]; }` part.

Comment: Unfortunately the problem keeps existing...

Comment: Aparently you did not understand the reuse logic. Am I right that the 8th row and the 1st row are not on screen at the same time? What happens is that the user scrolls and the cell 1 is invisible but cell 8 comes to view. Then cell 1 is reused to display cell 8. That's it.

Comment: BTW, looking at your code, which is fine for the most part, I believe that you are fare better of with subclassing UITableViewCell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    UILabel *artikel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:200];
    cell.selected = NO;
    [artikel setText:[_artikel objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];

    // Add this
    UILabel *menge = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:100]; 
    // As cell may have been reused menge already many have some value. 
    // Initialize menge with an appropriate value
    menge.text = @"";

   return cell;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The cell is dequeing and reusing values. If you want the cells to reflect the value, have a data source map that maps the cell indexpath.row to the index in the array